# OpenVPN ignoring openvpn.conf, throws unrecognized or missing option

Tags: linux, debian, vpn, openvpn, command-line-interface

I set up openVPN on Debian, but can't start the service.

```
[FAIL] Starting virtual private network daemon: openvpn failed!
```

Syslog says

```
Options error: Unrecognized option or missing parameter(s) in 
/etc/openvpn/openvpn.conf:11: ping-restart (2.2.1)
```

So I commented out that line, restarted the service, same error. After that I cut the line out, same error. I even rebooted the machine, same error. Somehow OpenVPN seems to parse another file than it is supposed to, nevertheless, I don't really understand what is happening.

For reference, my openvpn.conf:

```
port 1194
proto udp
mode server
tls-server
dev tun
server 10.6.0.0 255.255.255.0
client-to-client
push "route 192.168.0.0 255.255.255.0"

ping 10
ping-restart 120

ca /cert/vpn/ca.crt
cert /cert/vpn/server.crt
key /cert/vpn/server.key
dh /cert/vpn/dh2048.pem

#crl-verify crl.pem

keepalive 10 120
max-clients 10
#comp-lzo

user nobody
group nogroup
persist-key
persist-tun
verb 3

#client-config-dir /etc/openvpn/ccd

status openvpn.status
log-append /var/log/vpn.log
```

Comment: Read the init script and try to understand exactly what is happening. Which files are read? Which binary is started? Maybe you can start the daemon by hand in the foreground with debugging options enabled? It sure sounds like your daemon and you disagree about which config file to use :)